# Acumatica - How to call rest api from web ui?

Tags: rest, acumatica, erp

I have embedded javascript in the acumatica webfrontend and would like to make an ajax request to acumatica's contract-based rest api.

The call uses the same cookie as the webfrontend but gets the error 401. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code of the request to the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.